# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey..ctor(byte[] key)

Tags: c#, jwt

The application was working fine, but all of a sudden I can't  start the application and it throws the below error:

```
System.ArgumentException: IDX10703: Cannot create symmetric security key. Key length is zero.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey..ctor(Byte[] key) in C:\agent2\_work\56\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens\SymmetricSecurityKey.cs:line 51
   at TestCentral.Web.Startup.AuthConfigurer.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(JwtBearerOptions options) in C:\Users\Kamal Aliyu\Desktop\Central EPMS\src\TestCentral.Web.Mvc\Startup\AuthConfigurer.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
```

Code that throws the error

```
        {
            if (bool.Parse(configuration["Authentication:JwtBearer:IsEnabled"]))
            {
                services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.Audience = configuration["Authentication:JwtBearer:Audience"];
                        
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            // The signing key must match!
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["Authentication:JwtBearer:SecurityKey"])),

                            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidIssuer = configuration["Authentication:JwtBearer:Issuer"],

                            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidAudience = configuration["Authentication:JwtBearer:Audience"],

                            // Validate the token expiry
                            ValidateLifetime = true,

                            // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here
                            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                        };
                    });
                
            }
        }
```

it throws the error at the end of the method,

Comment: The error says: *Cannot create symmetric security key. Key length is zero.* - but we can't tell you why it happened, without knowing anything about your code or configuration.

Comment: @jps have added it

Comment: So it's probably this line `IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["Authentication:JwtBearer:SecurityKey"])),` . Check if there's a key in your configuration. And also put a breakpoint in that line and check if things get correctly loaded.

Comment: @jps when I check I found that a comer  was added in the config thanks man u save my time